# How to solve the differential equation?

Tags: python, statistics, differential-equations, curve, odeint

I want to solve the deferential equation

```
dydt = r * (Y ** p) * (1 - (Y / K) ** alpha)
```

I tried to write the code like :

```
def func(Y, r, p, K, alpha):
    dydt = r * (Y ** p) * (1 - (Y / K) ** alpha)
    return dydt
```

```
t = np.linspace(0, len(df), len(df))

# I used 1 to initialize my parameters ( is there a better way ?)
r = 1; p = 1; K = 1; alpha = 1 

y0 = r,p,K,alpha
```

```
ret = odeint(func, y0, t)
```

but when I try to execute the third block I get

> TypeError: func() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'p', 'K', and 'alpha'

However I tried to use  `ret = odeint(func, y0, t, args=(p,K, alpha))`
but this resulted in a three straight lines, when the equation is supposed to return a logistic curve.
how can I try to put **r** in the argument and why I need to specify the arguments? how can I get the final shape (logistic curve)

Note: to understand the parameters: Y represents the cumulative number of cases at time t, r is the growth rateat the early stage, and K is the final epidemic size.∈[0,1]is a parameter that allows the model to capture different growth profiles including the constant incidence (=0), sub-exponential growth (0<<1)and exponential growth (=1).

Comment: Hello, can you try to use `ret = odeint(lambda y0, t: func(t, *y0), y0, t)`? Is it work? I try to use lambda to swap the order of your parameter and unpack others.

Answer (score 1):

```
def func(Y, t, r, p, K, alpha):
    return r * (Y ** p) * (1 - (Y / K) ** alpha)
```

You must add the `t` parameter in the `ODEINT` method.

```
y0 = 0.5 # Your initial condition.
params = (1, 1, 1, 1) # r, p, K, alpha
sol = odeint(func, y0, t, args=params)
```

From the source! [Scipy ODEINT](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html)